# Do I have these recursive and closed forms correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

For the sequence: $0,1,5,12,22,35,51,70,92,117,145,176$
I have the closed form (dashes indicate subtext): $$a_n=\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}$$
For recursive: $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+3n^2+5n+2}{2}$$

If they are wrong, please explain how to solve.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to learn to format on this site. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, consider giving [check marks](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to respondents. You can up vote at 15 rep.

Comment: You can check them through induction.  That is, see if assuming the first form works makes it work for $n+1$, then prove for $n=0$.  For the second one, do the same, but prove for $n+1$ and $n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

They are pentagonal numbers
$$
 p_n = \tfrac{3n^2-n}{2} 
$$
for n ≥ 1. 
The recursive formula is
$$
\begin{align}
p_1 &= 1\\
p_n & =p_{n-1}+3n-2\qquad\text{for }n\ge 2
\end{align}
$$